# Why does this bootstrap dropdown disappear when one item is clicked but not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

The following item list code is inside of a navbar with navbar-fixed-top.  The code below is output that was originally written as haml code.

Why does the "Manage Teams" item close the dropdown menu, but "Add sale ..." does not?

```
<li class="dropdown open" id="settings-drop">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </a>
  <ul aria-labelledby="settings-drop" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a data-remote="true" href="http://localhost:3000/sales/new?referer=notifications" role="menuitem">Add sale ...</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="/affiliates" role="menuitem">Manage Teams</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

It seems like the `data-remote="true"` hash is somehow interfering with bootstraps ability to detect the item being clicked on and close it.

Comment: there's no add event button, u mean add sale ?

Comment: According to http://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/ the data-remote is stopping click event propagation which bootstrap relies upon.  I can't find a solution though other than not using the ajax call in the dropdown item.